# Is there a more formal term for "scrambling" a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations, notation, terminology, time-series

Is there a more proper way to describe scrambling a sequence, i.e assigning the same values to different indices either randomly or algorithmically?

Comment: Permuting? ${}{}$

Comment: I agree with @copper.hat  One sequence is a **permutation** of the other.

Comment: And if you need a notation for the new sequence: If $(a_n)$ is your sequence then a permutation of the sequence is given by $(a_{\sigma(n)})$ where $\sigma : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a bijection.